windows terminal run .sh in wsl distro in the linux context
i'm currently trying to configure a windows terminal profile to launch directly in a wsl distro (Ubuntu) and run a .sh-file in the linux context which doesn't seem to work, in the distro node is installed and opening the terminal with the Ubuntu-profile and manually run node -v returns the correct version node -v result but when i try to run it through a command line i get  "node command not found" that also happens when i run the .sh-file, which runs some node commands, so i figured that the wsl.exe/ubuntu.exe commandline's i found googleing somehow don't run in the linux-context ?
i tried the following commands:
ubuntu.exe run bash -e -c 'node -v'

wsl.exe bash -e -c 'node -v'

node -v

the last one just returns error XXXX when launching 'node -v' so i'm guessing that's just plain wrong syntax
is there a way to tell windows-terminal/wsl to run the command after the terminal opened as that seems to work ? or a way to pass the commands trough ?
thanks in advance for any help here :)
edit: to clarify what i'm trying to do:

create a "windows terminal"-profile that launches in the wsl Ubuntu environment
after launching it should run a .sh-file from my home-directory (~/launch.sh)

both i got working with:
    {
        "guid": "{92c51ff0-b673-4f3e-b0dc-ce33359df292}",
        "name": "Ubuntu-Launch",
        "commandline": "ubuntu.exe run bash -e -c '~/launch.sh'",
        "icon": "https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/49a1a858-favicon-32x32.png",
    }

as the profile, except i get the error "node command not found" if i change the commandline part to "commandline": "ubuntu.exe" (the default) open the terminal and enter ~/launch.sh it works just fine, so what i'm asking is what commandline parameters do i need to set to get it to work essentially

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
